# How do I calculate a linear regression by reading an external file an print out the slope and y intercept

Tags: python

How can I write a Python program that computes both the slope and the y-intercept of the
regression line and stores them in variables m and c respectively.

Comment: Before asking such a general question, you should try to divide the task and tackle each of them methodically with the help of online ressources:
1. Reading files with python 2. Loading data in the right data structure 3. Compute a linear regression

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.